# advice on learning slangs

Tags: slang

I'd like to learn some slangs, because sometimes I don't understand native speakers' conversations. However, I don't know what slangs to remember, and what to skip. I'm afraid some slangs will quickly fade into history after I learn them. Any advice?

Comment: Slang changes very quickly. Both in time and over distance. The only way you can really "learn" it is to talk to a large number of local speakers. And then you go out of style in a very short time. Consider. When was the last time somebody greeted you with "Shadily my Brother!" For about a year you could hardly avoid that in certain sub-cultures.

Comment: Beware of teaching slang. When I was at school, our French teacher (who was English) told us that young French folks said _formid_ (from _formidable_) when they meant 'cool', 'great', exciting', etc. The first time I used it on a lovely French girl when I was about 18, she burst out laughing and said it was something her father might have said around 1940.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slang is not something you can learn in any formal sense because slang is incredibly tied to whatever community you find yourself part of. People who occupy the same geographic area but not the same circle of acquaintances can easily have entirely different slang vocabularies. It's just something you have to figure out based on whoever you personally communicate with (particularly face-to-face).